# Html page with SVG file doesn't scale by Height

Tags: html, svg

I want to manage SVG with help JS and  created simple Html page for rendering SVG, but scale by Height doesn't work in Browser. Why?

How do I have to write template HTML page for scaling SVG file on a full page?

SVGHTML.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang='en'>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=10' />
<head>
</head>
<body style='margin: 0; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%'>
<object id='SVG' height = "100%" width = "100%"   type='image/svg+xml' data=image.svg></object>
</body>
</html>
```

image.svg

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg2"
   width="100%" 
   height="100%"
   preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
   viewBox="0 0 300 300"
   >
  <metadata
     id="metadata14">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs12" />
  <text
     id="text4"
     font-size="24"
     y="50"
     x="25">SVG Circle Element</text>
  <text
     id="text6"
     y="275"
     x="25">Click the circle to change its size.</text>
  <circle
     id="circle8"
     onclick="doCircle(evt)"
     stroke-width="5"
     stroke="green"
     fill="pink"
     r="50"
     cy="150"
     cx="125" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found decision. Cascading style sheets  [CSS 2.1 - 10.5](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-height) says  the percentage height is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'. For absolutely positioned elements whose containing block is based on a block container element, the percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the padding box of that element. This is a change from CSS1, where the percentage width was always calculated with respect to the content box of the parent element.

So I have to use style `position:absolute` in tag object with SVG file.